# AWS IAM API Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, permissions, amazon-iam, endpoint

I've been looking for an API that returns the various privileges assigned for IAM in AWS. I haven't found anything on the AWS site or third party services that do this. Am I missing this or does it not exist? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Clarification:
If I'm the owner of an AWS organization or account, I want to be able to answer questions like

What resources does this user have access to?

Who has access to resource x?

etc etc...

Is there an API that can provide the answer to these questions?

Comment: "various privileges assigned for IAM in AWS" - what do you mean by that? Do you have any example of such API?

Comment: Are you looking for an API that basically answers "what permissions does a given set of AWS credentials have?" Generally speaking, that doesn't exist. You'd first need IAM permissions to actually call IAM to retrieve policies and then you'd need to aggregate and parse policies.

Comment: If I'm the owner of an AWS organization or account, I want to be able to answer questions like

What resources does this user have access to?
Who has access to resource x?

Is there an API that can provide the answer to these questions?

Answer (score 0):

The API for IAM can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/welcome.html